# iOS tableView not populating with data

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can someone explain to me why this isn't populating my tableView inside my viewController? I can make it work inside a UITableViewController, but it won't fill with data when i make a UIViewController with a tableView in it. In my storyboard I have created a view controller with a tableview and a table view cell.  When i run the program all i get is my empty tableView. Yet it works just fine in a UITableViewController

.h

```
   //MainViewController.h
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
    {
        NSArray *topItems;
        NSMutableArray *subItems; // array of arrays

        int currentExpandedIndex;
    }
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;


    @end
```

.m

```
    ///MainController.m
    #import "MainViewController.h"

    #define NUM_TOP_ITEMS 5
    #define NUM_SUBITEMS 6

    @interface MainViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation MainViewController

    - (id)init {
        self = [super init];

        if (self) {
            topItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self topLevelItems]];
            subItems = [NSMutableArray new];
            currentExpandedIndex = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < [topItems count]; i++) {
                [subItems addObject:[self subItems]];
            }
        }
        return self;
    }

    #pragma mark - Data generators

    - (NSArray *)topLevelItems {
        NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TOP_ITEMS; i++) {
            [items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d", i + 1]];
        }

        return items;
    }

    - (NSArray *)subItems {
        NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
        int numItems = arc4random() % NUM_SUBITEMS + 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            [items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SubItem %d", i + 1]];
        }

        return items;
    }

    #pragma mark - View management

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [topItems count] + ((currentExpandedIndex > -1) ? [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : 0);
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *ParentCellIdentifier = @"ParentCell";
        static NSString *ChildCellIdentifier = @"ChildCell";

        BOOL isChild =
        currentExpandedIndex > -1
        && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex
        && indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];

        UITableViewCell *cell;

        if (isChild) {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChildCellIdentifier];
        }
        else {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
        }


        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier] ;
        }

        if (isChild) {
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - currentExpandedIndex - 1];
        }
        else {
            int topIndex = (currentExpandedIndex > -1 && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex)
            ? indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count]
            : indexPath.row;

            cell.textLabel.text = [topItems objectAtIndex:topIndex];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
        }

        return cell;
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view delegate

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        BOOL isChild =
        currentExpandedIndex > -1
        && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex
        && indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];

        if (isChild) {
            NSLog(@"A child was tapped, do what you will with it");
            return;
        }

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        if (currentExpandedIndex == indexPath.row) {
            [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
            currentExpandedIndex = -1;
        }
        else {

            BOOL shouldCollapse = currentExpandedIndex > -1;

            if (shouldCollapse) {
                [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
            }

            currentExpandedIndex = (shouldCollapse && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex) ? indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : indexPath.row;

            [self expandItemAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
        }

        [self.tableView endUpdates];

    }

    - (void)expandItemAtIndex:(int)index {
        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSArray *currentSubItems = [subItems objectAtIndex:index];
        int insertPos = index + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < [currentSubItems count]; i++) {
            [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertPos++ inSection:0]];
        }
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

    }

    - (void)collapseSubItemsAtIndex:(int)index {
        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i = index + 1; i <= index + [[subItems objectAtIndex:index] count]; i++) {
            [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        }
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }

    - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
        return YES;
    }

    @end
```

Comment: And watch for Rick´s answer. You must also set the delegates.

Comment: Thanks Mirko, Ricks answered didn't seem to help. Please see comment below on Ricks post for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

In a UITableViewController, the tableView's delegate and data source is automatically set for you since it is the main view. But this isn't the case for a tableView, being a subview, in a UIViewController. You need to add the 2 statements manually.

Edit:

I copied your code to a new project and found several other issues:

Before that, make sure your IB is connected to your tableView in storyboard like meda said. I had assumed that you know this.

1. In AppDelegate.m, use the following code since you are using storyboard (main.storyboard in my case).

   ```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   MainViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
   self.window.rootViewController = vc;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   ```

This solves the black screen issue. (First, an error in your comment where you try to initialise a UITableViewController instead of MainViewController. Second, when you use something like `[viewController alloc] init]`, you created a new instance of "viewController" and NOT using the storyboard.)

1. Your `init` method will not be called using the storyboard way. So, in `viewDidLoad`, call `init`. I would prefer to change / rename it to, say, `loadData` though.

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad 
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       [self init];
       self.tableView.dataSource = self;
       self.tableView.delegate = self;
   }
   ```

I am seeing what you want nicely on my simulator.

Comment: Hmm...didnt seem to work. In my appDelegate.m I am just returning YES for me didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. However, when I i use the UITableViewController version, I am implementing this within the method:   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    
    AccordionTableViewController *vc = [AccordionTableViewController new];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    
    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];                                          When i try to implement this code in my tableView version, all I get is a black screen.

Comment: In my UITableViewController version i did not use IB at all, however, in my UIViewController version I did. Could this mean something?

Comment: WOW! Rick if i could HUG you I would. I have worked on this forever couldn't figure out what the heck was going on. Thank you so so much for the time and effort you have given to help me out. You rock!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition of what the other said, from storyboard:

You should link the `UITableView` to `tableView` property by holding <kbd>command</kbd>, then drag and drop it on the property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

This is done by default when using a `UITableViewController`.  You have to implement everything when you use a `UIViewController`. So make sure `IBOutlets`, `delegate` and `datasources` are all hooked up.

Answer (score 0):

i don´t see

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Only when this method is called, the table with their values​​, rendered.